# Сумма цифр. Python

Tags: python

Задача сложить цифры любого числа между собой, если полученная сумма больше 9 - еще раз сложить и так пока не останется число из одной цифры.

После if если полученное число больше 9 хотел его вернуть обратно в функцию, как можно это сделать? или есть лучшее решение?

```
def digital_root(n):
    n = list(str(n))
    n2 = [int(item) for item in n]
    sum_1 = sum(n2)
    if sum_1 > 9:

    else:
        return sum_1
```

Comment: Ну так вставьте туда вызов функции  `return digital_root(sum_1)`.

Comment: Не ответ на вопрос, но возможно будет полезно. Если число больше нуля, то его цифровой корень равен `(n - 1) % 9 + 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def sum_of(num):  
    while num > 9:
        num = sum(int(n) for n in str(num))    
    return num
```

Comment: Спасибо, так и знал что нужен цикл а не вот это вот все (

Comment: *Если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.*